# Why Java double print format differs depending on using String.format or not

Tags: java, floating-point, format, locale

This code:

```
 System.out.println(String.format("%f", Math.PI));
 System.out.println(Math.PI);
```

produces that result on my computer:

```
3,141593
3.141592653589793
```

Why does the first line print float number with comma while the second one uses dot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.format(String, Object...)` uses the formatting rules from `Locale.getDefault()`.  `String.valueOf(double)` does not.  Use `String.format(Locale, String, Object...)` to explicitly specify the locale to use.

Answer (score 2):

The former respects your locale settings (which seems to use comma for thousand separator).

Answer (score 0):

The first one uses the [default locale](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

The [second](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) one probably uses a default (not localizable) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

String.format() uses the locale of your system. There should also be a variant of that method, you can pass a specific Locale instance. When using println() on the other hand, the object's toString() method is invoked - in your case Double#toString(), which is mosten times a rather basic implementation, just good enough to present a understandable display of of the object.